# SQL - query same table

Tags: sql-server

All,

Some time ago I asked how to construct a query to do the following related to a forecast process we run here. I have created some tables in SQL: 
-          What I want to do is querying the most recent timestamps of a unique combination of the fields Year, Month, Unit, Version, Currency, ERS, Region, ToolCode, Timestamp. To explain this:
o   Each unique combination (version) could have multiple lines in the table where people may adjust their forecast and produce the same line only with a different timestamp in the tables; 
o   I then need to query from the SQL server the most recent forecast (most recent timestamp);
-          To solve this I should actually do a subquery containing the max of timestamp field and inner join this on the same table. I came up with the following code but some it is not working yet:

```
SELECT A.Year,
    A.Month,
    A.Unit,
    A.[Affiliate Unit],
    A.Version,
    A.Currency,
    A.ERS,
    A.Region,
    A.Value,
    A.ToolCode,
    A.TIMESTAMP,
    A.LineCode
FROM dbo.TBL_FC_EXP_IC AS A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT B.Year,
        B.Month,
        B.Unit,
        B.Version,
        B.Currency,
        B.ERS,
        B.Region,
        B.ToolCode,
        Max(B.TIMESTAMP) AS B.MaxTimestamp
    FROM dbo.TBL_FC_EXP_IC AS B
    GROUP BY B.Year,
        B.Month,
        B.Unit,
        B.Version,
        B.Currency,
        B.ERS,
        B.Region,
        B.ToolCode
    ) B ON (B.YEAR = A.YEAR)
    AND (B.Month = A.Month)
    AND (B.Unit = A.Unit)
    AND (B.Version = A.Version)
    AND (B.Region = A.Region)
    AND (B.ToolCode = A.ToolCode)
    AND (B.MaxTimestamp = A.TIMESTAMP);
```

It now gives me the error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your error is in that field alias in your subquery: `Max(B.TIMESTAMP) AS B.MaxTimestamp` should just read `Max(B.TIMESTAMP) AS MaxTimestamp`. An alias is just a name you give an object. It has no reference to any other object. Kind of like a variable.

Comment: Great it works. Thanks for your help